# Conditional coloring of rows in df.to_html() table

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to change color of text in the rows of a table created using df.to_html()
Condition is if text "Critical" exists in a column then whole row's text should be Red colored.

Sample Table -

```
Severity      Name        Description      Type
              ABC         lorem ipsum      Car
Critical      DEF         something        Bike
              GHI         foo data         Car

High          XYZ         numbers          Car
```

The rows with Critical (i.e., Name: ABC, DEF, GHI) should get text colored red.
Below is the code I tried initially

```
html_table = df.to_html()
html_table = html_table.replace('<td>{}</td>'.format(), '<td style="color:red;">{}</td>'.format()
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function that goes through each row of the dataframe and checks the content of the `Severity` column. Once this is done, it colors all cells of that row Red.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Severity': ['', 'Critical', '', 'High'],
    'Name': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'XYZ'],
    'Description': ['lorem ipsum', 'something', 'foo data', 'numbers'],
    'Type': ['Car', 'Bike', 'Car', 'Car']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def color_critical_rows(df):
    html = df.to_html(index=False)

    rows = html.split('</tr>')
    new_rows = []

    for row in rows:
        if 'Critical' in row:
            new_row = row.replace('<td>', '<td style="color: red;">')
        else:
            new_row = row
        new_rows.append(new_row)

    new_html = '</tr>'.join(new_rows)

    return new_html

colored_html_table = color_critical_rows(df)
print(colored_html_table)
```

giving you this output:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>Severity</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Car</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="color: red;">Critical</td>
      <td style="color: red;">DEF</td>
      <td style="color: red;">something</td>
      <td style="color: red;">Bike</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>GHI</td>
      <td>foo data</td>
      <td>Car</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>High</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
      <td>numbers</td>
      <td>Car</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the solution but somehow it is working only for the first row i.e., The row having 'ABC' , The Critical is the merged cell for top 3 rows. Table is the result of a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pandas styler to set up your conditional formatting. Something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

CRITICAL = 'critical'

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'severity': ['critical', 'critical', 'critical', 'high'],
    'name': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'XYZ'],
    'description': ['lorem ipsum', 'something', 'foo data', 'numbers'],
    'type': ['car', 'bike', 'car', 'car']
})

# sets the style for all cells in the row if the severity is critical
def cond(x):
    if x.severity == CRITICAL: 
         return ['background-color: red'] * len(x)

df_styled = df.style.apply(cond, axis=1)
print(df_styled.to_html())
```

This generates the CSS section of your HTML, and an HTML table with IDs matching the CSS selectors (not as pretty as being able to add a specific class to the entire `tr` element, but it gets the job done)

For more information, see Pandas's [official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) about `style.apply`

Comment: Pandas styler also has the ability to add CSS classes using the method `set_td_classes`

Comment: it can add class to `tr` via the method `set_table_styles`

Comment: @Attack68: thanks, that's good to know. I'm not too familiar with Pandas. I might revise my answer later to reflect that. I didn't really like the auto-generated attributes that Pandas generated for the rows.